# Error while configuring Grafana SMTP with AWS SES

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, amazon-ses

Below is the helm chart values configuration I am using to setup Grafana smtp settings

```
grafana.ini:
  server:
    root_url: https://grafana.example.com
  smtp:
    enabled: true
    host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
    startTLS_policy: MandatoryStartTLS
    user: AKIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    password: ‘XClyrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX’
    skip_verify: true
    from_address: alert@example.com
    from_name: Grafana
```

However, getting below error

```
Email cannot be sent. 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid”
```